# How to print a number as exponent in R

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8

Figures can be displayed as exponent in unicode, like ¹. How can I use that to convert an arbitrary number to a string with exponent characters, and print that with R?

I can print figures 1 and 2 using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts but the other figures and minus doesn't work.

FWIW, I use Rstudio on Windows.

Comment: Do you mean in showing and exponent in the console? or in an output document? If it is in the console why can't a variable defined as your exponent be used?

Comment: In the console. I currently print things like "kg^2 . m^-1", but it is ugly

Comment: it's going to be **very** hard to do in the console.

Comment: Why ? It is "just" utf8 characters

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, unicode has support for all digits in a superscript form, so it should not be a problem if you can print/render UTF-8 characters. The problem is that the font you will use to display the string must support those characters and I guess most of them do not. If you are printing to a console, check out what font it uses and check if that font supports the characters you want to print.